# Word frequency analysis: Python

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a very rudimentary code that counts sentences and words in the arbitrary text.

Code:

```
class analyse():


    def __init__(self,text):
        self.text = text


    def sentence_count(self):
        punctuation_marks = ['\.','\?','!', '\."','\.”']
        space_newline_end = [' ', '\n', '$']
        combine = ['({}({}|{}|{}))'.format(x,*space_newline_end) for x in punctuation_marks]
        pattern_string = '|'.join(combine)
        sentence_search = re.compile(r'{}'.format(pattern_string))
        count = len(sentence_search.findall(self.text))
        return count


    def word_search(self):
        '''Returns all words in the text (repetitions are included)'''
        word_pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+)((\’\w+)|(-\w+)|(\'\w+))?')
        find_all = word_pattern.findall(self.text)
        return [''.join(x[:2]).lower() for x in find_all]


    def unique_words(self):
        return set(self.word_search())


    def unique_words_count(self):
        return {x : (self.word_search()).count(x) for x in self.unique_words()}


    def most_frequent(self,n,reverse):
        '''Returns n most (reverse == False) / least (reverse == True) frequent words.'''
        uniq_words = self.unique_words_count()
        if n > len(uniq_words):
            print("Number of unique words is less than {}.".format(n))
            return None
        words = list(uniq_words.keys())
        count = [[list(uniq_words.values())[x],x] for x in range(len(uniq_words))]
        count_sorted = sorted(count,key = lambda x: x[0],reverse=True)
        words_sorted = [words[x[1]] for x in count_sorted]
        if reverse == False:
            for y in range(n):
                print('Word: {}. {} \t \t  |||| Count: {}'.format(y+1,words_sorted[y],count_sorted[y][0]))
        if reverse == True:
            iterator = 1
            for y in range(len(uniq_words)-1,len(uniq_words)-n-1,-1):
                print('Word: {}. {}  \t \t |||| Count: {}'.format(iterator,words_sorted[y],count_sorted[y][0]))
                iterator+=1


    def search_specific_word_count(self,word):
        if word in self.unique_words_count():
            print('Word: {} || Count: {}'.format(word,self.unique_words_count()[word]))
        else:
            print('"{}" is not found.'.format(word))
```

What can be improved?

---

*If you don't need an example, you can skip following part.*

Example:

Consider following passage:

> When Matt Radwell, a customer support officer for a small local
>   authority in the UK, first started answering queries from the area’s
>   residents, it was a frustrating and time-consuming business. If a
>   resident contacted Aylesbury Vale District Council, 40 miles north of
>   London, about an issue like housing benefit in which he lacked
>   expertise, Mr Radwell might keep the caller waiting as long as 20
>   minutes. He had to find someone who could give him the relevant
>   information.

Let the variable that hold the passage above be called `passage`

Firstly we instantiate class

`p1 = analyse(passage)`

Now let's have a look at each function:

```
Input: p1.sentence_count()
Output: 3


Input: p1.word_search()

Output: ['when', 'matt', 'radwell', 'a', 'customer', 'support', 'officer', 'for', 'a', 'small', 'local', 'authority', 'in', 'the', 'uk', 'first', 'started', 'answering', 'queries', 'from', 'the', 'area’s', 'residents', 'it', 'was', 'a', 'frustrating', 'and', 'time-consuming', 'business', 'if', 'a', 'resident', 'contacted', 'aylesbury', 'vale', 'district', 'council', '40', 'miles', 'north', 'of', 'london', 'about', 'an', 'issue', 'like', 'housing', 'benefit', 'in', 'which', 'he', 'lacked', 'expertise', 'mr', 'radwell', 'might', 'keep', 'the', 'caller', 'waiting', 'as', 'long', 'as', '20', 'minutes', 'he', 'had', 'to', 'find', 'someone', 'who', 'could', 'give', 'him', 'the', 'relevant', 'information']


Input: p1.unique_words()

Output: {'20', '40', 'a', 'about', 'an', 'and', 'answering', 'area’s', 'as', 'authority', 'aylesbury', 'benefit', 'business', 'caller', 'contacted', 'could', 'council', 'customer', 'district', 'expertise', 'find', 'first', 'for', 'from', 'frustrating', 'give', 'had', 'he', 'him', 'housing', 'if', 'in', 'information', 'issue', 'it', 'keep', 'lacked', 'like', 'local', 'london', 'long', 'matt', 'might', 'miles', 'minutes', 'mr', 'north', 'of', 'officer', 'queries', 'radwell', 'relevant', 'resident', 'residents', 'small', 'someone', 'started', 'support', 'the', 'time-consuming', 'to', 'uk', 'vale', 'waiting', 'was', 'when', 'which', 'who'}


Input: p1.unique_words_count()

Output: {'was': 1, 'queries': 1, 'radwell': 2, 'the': 4, 'caller': 1, 'waiting': 1, 'area’s': 1, 'and': 1, 'first': 1, 'north': 1, 'a': 4, 'give': 1, 'like': 1, 'housing': 1, 'as': 2, 'him': 1, 'from': 1, 'he': 2, 'might': 1, 'someone': 1, 'who': 1, 'it': 1, 'issue': 1, 'miles': 1, 'lacked': 1, 'started': 1, 'benefit': 1, '20': 1, 'minutes': 1, 'an': 1, 'council': 1, 'time-consuming': 1, 'resident': 1, 'officer': 1, 'uk': 1, 'expertise': 1, 'had': 1, 'support': 1, 'small': 1, 'answering': 1, 'which': 1, 'customer': 1, 'matt': 1, 'if': 1, 'mr': 1, 'in': 2, 'aylesbury': 1, 'london': 1, 'frustrating': 1, 'long': 1, 'when': 1, 'contacted': 1, 'district': 1, 'relevant': 1, '40': 1, 'could': 1, 'information': 1, 'residents': 1, 'about': 1, 'keep': 1, 'of': 1, 'to': 1, 'find': 1, 'authority': 1, 'local': 1, 'business': 1, 'for': 1, 'vale': 1}


Input: p1.most_frequent(1,reverse=False) 
Output: 'Word: 1. the         |||| Count: 4'

Input: p1.most_frequent(2,reverse=False) 
Output: 'Word: 1. the         |||| Count: 4
         Word: 2. a           |||| Count: 4'

Input: p1.most_frequent(100,reverse=False)
Output: 'Number of unique words is less than 100.'
```

If you want words that occur least often, set reverse for True

```
Input: p1.most_frequent(1,reverse=True)
Output: 'Word: 1. vale           |||| Count: 1'
```

You can also check frequency of the specific word, for example:

```
Input: p1.search_specific_word_count('customer')
Output: 'Word: customer || Count: 1'
```

If you want to check the word that is not in the text, then output will be

```
Input: p1.search_specific_word_count('president')
Output: '"president" is not found.'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Redundant processing

Some of the code processes the text multiple times.  For example:

```
def unique_words_count(self):
    return {x : (self.word_search()).count(x) for x in self.unique_words()}
```

scans the text twice and scans a list of all the words:

1. `self.word_search()` calls `word_pattern.findall()`
2. `.count(x)` scans the list of words
3. `self.unique_words()` calls `word_search()` which calls `word_pattern.findall()`

All of the analysis can be obtained by processing the text once to build a dictionary of items in the text.  The various methods can the return information based on the dictionary.

#### collections module

The `collections` library provides a `Counter` class designed for counting things.

```
counts = Counter(sequence)    # counts items in the sequence
```

#### regex

The regex patterns can be simplified:

```
word_pattern = r"\w+(?:[-’']\w+)?"

sentence_ending = r'[.?!](?=\s|"|”|$)'   # .?! only if followed by white space, quote, or end-of-string.
```

I also added a regex to catch a few abbreviations, so they won't be picked up as sentence endings.  Obviously, this can be expanded.

#### Separate viewing from processing

Rather than directly printing out some data, it is often better for a class to return a string representation of the data.  This makes the class more flexible.  For example, if you want to use the Analysis class as part of a web server.  The string should be sent to the web browser, not printed on the server's screen. (Although, some web frameworks take care of this for you).

#### revised code

```
import re
import itertools as it

from collections import Counter, deque


class Analyse:

    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

        abbreviations = r"Dr\.|Mr\.|Mrs\."

        word_pattern = r"\w+(?:[-’']\w+)?"

        sentence_ending = r'[.?!](?=\s|"|”|$)'

        pattern_string = '|'.join([abbreviations, word_pattern, sentence_ending])

        search_pattern = re.compile(pattern_string)

        self.counts = Counter(match[0].lower() for match in search_pattern.finditer(text))

        # pulls sentence endings out of self.counts, so the methods don't need
        # to filter them out
        self.sentence_endings = sum(self.counts.pop(p, 0) for p in '.?!')

        # length of longest word
        self.maxlen = max(len(w) for w in self.counts)       


    def sentence_count(self):
        return self.sentence_endings


    def all_words(self):
        '''Returns all words in the text (repetitions are included)'''
        return list(self.counts.elements())


    def unique_words(self):
        return list(self.counts.keys())


    def word_counts(self, word=None):
        if word:
            return self.counts[word]
        else:
            return dict(self.counts)


    def most_frequent(self, n):
        '''Returns n most frequent words.'''
        return self.counts.most_common(n)


    def least_frequent(self, n):
        return self.counts.most_common()[-n:]


    def most_frequent_as_str(self, n):
        s = [f"Word {i}: {word:{self.maxlen}} |||| Count: {count}" for i, (word, count) in enumerate(self.most_frequent(n))]
        return '\n'.join(s)


    def least_frequent_as_str(self, n):
        s = [f"Word {i}: {word:{self.maxlen}} |||| Count: {count}" for i, (word, count) in enumerate(self.least_frequent(n))]
        return '\n'.join(s)
```

Several of the methods end with `return list(...)` or `return dict(...)`.  The calls to `list` or `dict` are probably not needed, but I put them in to match the data structures returned by your code.

Comment: Thanks for the review! One question: you wrote `word_pattern = r"\w+(?:[-’']\w+)?"` What is `?:`  for?

Comment: One more thing: the name of my class was called "analyse", but you instead wrote "Analyse". Is there a reason for that? (Like, for example, convention for writing names of the classes)

Comment: And one more: `sentence_ending = r'[.?!](?=\s|"|”|$)'` I get everything except `?=` part. What is it for?

Comment: And one more: you imported `deque` from `collections`, but I haven't seen you using it anywhere. Why?

Comment: @Nelver It is `Analysis` because of [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the import is probably an oversight (maybe they used it instead of `pop` for `self.sentence_endings`?). `?=` is a [positive look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). So it matches only of the pattern will come afterwards. `?:` is [quite similar, but not quite the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10804846/4042267).

Comment: `(?:...)` is like using `(...)`, but the regex engine doesn't save the results. So you can't get it using `.group()`.  As Graipher said classes should start with a capital letter.  `p1(?=p2)` means that p1 matches if p2 would match next, but it doesn't "use up" the p2.  `deque` was left over from a previous version of the code.